# Spectral norm of similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-norm, similar-matrices

In the table it says that if $$A=P B P^{-1}$$ then spectral norm is the same for

1. Similar matrices.
2. Unitary similar matrices.

Is the first statement (1) true? If $A=P B P^{-1}$  (where $P$ is not a unitary matrix)?

Comment: Which table? What is a 2-norm? Please provide a link or define in the post.

Answer (score 2):

a) is not true: the matrices
$$
A=\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2}
$$
and
$$
B=\pmatrix{ 1 & n \\ 0 & 2}
$$
are similar as their Jordan normal form is equal to $A$, but $\|A\|_2 = 2$, $\|B\|_2 \ge n \to \infty$ for $n\to \infty$.

In case you like, here is the explicit transformation:
One can check that $A = S^{-1}BS$ with $S=\pmatrix{ 1 & n \\ 0 & 1}$ so $S^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&-n\\0&1}$.

Comment: Oh... right... different eigenvalues... I'm dumb,

Comment: Thanks. I know in addition that S^{-1} is bounded.

Comment: I know that S is symmetric and the 2-norm of S^{-1} is bounded. I ask now is the 2-norm of  B=S^{-1} A S  bounded, given that A is diagonal with positive entries which are bonded by 1.